# Update templated parent while design-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` namespace for custom window chrome. I have `Textblock` in `ControlTemplate` of my window:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" 
           FontSize="16" FontFamily="SegoiUI" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

So, this `TextBlock` shows my window `Title`. The problem is, that value of `TextBlock` is not visible in design-time:

[image: Window at design-time]

When I launch my application, window title appears:

[image: Window at run-time]

How can I make `TextBlock` show it's text in the window constructor?

Comment: Use fallback or targetnull in your binding

Comment: It looks like Visual studio creates a proxy for windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19680852/548304